# Fiddlerscript to send a modified request to the server wont work

Tags: javascript, json, http, post, fiddler

Ive created a fiddlescript rule that I thought would wait for a specific object:value, automatically send the a portion of the json value back to a different URI as a post request with the same header information such as cookies.

When the script is activated I receive an error. I assume its something to do with the json object value.

```js
    static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {
        if (oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type", "application/json")) {
            oSession["ui-backcolor"] = "blue"; 
            oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
        }
        if (oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type", "application/json") && oSession.utilFindInResponse("faceId", false) > -1) {
            oSession["ui-backcolor"] = "green"; 
            oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
            var oBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(oSession.requestBodyBytes);
            var j = Fiddler.WebFormats.JSON.JsonDecode(oBody);
            var facId = j.JSONObject["faceId"];
            var reqBod = '{"faceId":"' + facId + '"}';
            oSession.oRequest.headers.HTTPMethod == "POST";
            oSession.utilSetRequestBody(reqBod);
            oSession.url = "https://urltosendpostrequest.com/Search";
            FiddlerObject.utilIssueRequest(oSession);
        }
```

I expected the server to accept the modified POST request but instead the script runs into an error.

```
FiddlerScript OnBeforeResponse0 failed. X 
There was a problem with your FiddlerScript. 
Function expected Function expected at Microsoft.)Script.Latainding.CallValue(Object val, Objects arguments, Boolean construct, Boolean brackets, VsaEngine engine, Object thisob, Binder binder, Culturelnfo culture, Strings namedParameters) at Microsoft.JScript.Latainding.Call(Binder binder, Objects arguments, ParameterModifier]] modifiers, Culturelnfo culture, Strings namedParameters, Boolean construct, Boolean brackets, VsaEngine engine) at Microsoft.JScript.Latainding.Call(ObjectS arguments, Boolean construct, Boolean brackets, VsaEngine engine) at Fiddler.ScriptNamespace.Handlers.OnBeforeResponse(Session oSession) at Fiddler.ScriptBase. 1:1(Session OD) in CA.lenkins\Fiddler_Windows\workspace\Fiddler2\Common\Application\ Scripting\ScriptBase.csiline 921
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing access to the request and the response header/body. Also it seems that it is not clear to you that the `POST` data belongs to the request not the response. Therefore make sure you are manipulating the correct data (the request or the response).

Or do you want to capture the request and send a custom response back to the client? If yes you should look at the [AutoResponder Flag `x-replywithfile`](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledgebase/sessionflags).

You script has code in `OnBeforeResponse` therefore you can only access properties and methods that are related to the response. 
However you have the following code which tries to access the request (which is of course impossible as the request has already been forwarded):

```
oSession.oRequest.headers.HTTPMethod == "POST";
oSession.utilSetRequestBody(reqBod);
FiddlerObject.utilIssueRequest(oSession);
```

Comment: First off thank you Robert(with snowman as cool* avatar), on my journey of learning I will not forget you. I want to capture the GET response and send a custom POST request back to the server. The JSON object that im trying to send as custom POST request data with a copy of the header should be captured from the server as GET response.

Comment: Pardon my lack of http lingo. What I mean when I say 'capture the GET response' is manipulate the data the server provided under the GET Response header.

Comment: @Double What you write is still confusing as you seem to mix up client and server. A GET request is sent by the client and received by the server - the the response makes the opposite way back. Regarding the generated autoresponse this seem to be bit more difficult: https://www.telerik.com/forums/autorespond-with-script#L4pcg_nH8UKEg2vDu_juSQ If you don't mind that the server receives the request you should better just let the request go through and later manipulate the response in `OnBeforeResponse`. However as I wrote in this method do not manipulate the request!

Comment: You have pardoned my skiddy use of lingo and have corrected me politely and for that you have my full respect. The GET response from the server is what holds the value that i need in order to properly send a useful POST request back to the server completing the script. I dont mind the server receiving the original GET request because that is the only way I (the client) can receive the object:value in the response that I want to send back to the server as custom (but looks original) POST request. So you are correct on the fact that i need to change `utilSetRequestBody` to `utilSetResponseBody`

Comment: Changed `utilSetRequestBody` to `utilSetResponseBody` but im still getting an error, ive edited the original question to reflect the error im getting.